# How to use Asyncio module in migrate database from Sqlite to Postgres?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlite, python-asyncio

I have a script to migrate database from Sqlite to Postgres. My original scipt works, but when I try to use Asyncio to speed up program, my new code even running slower than the original a few seconds. The transfer speed of tables is very slow. Can anyone suggest to me, where am I wrong ?

My original code :

```
import psycopg2, sqlite3, sys
import time

start_time = time.time()

sqdb="D://Python//SqliteToPostgreFull//testmydb6.db" #folder contain sqlite db
sqlike="table"
pgdb="testmydb7" #postgres db
pguser="postgres"
pgpswd="1234"
pghost="127.0.0.1"
pgport="5432"

consq=sqlite3.connect(sqdb)
cursq=consq.cursor()

tabnames=[]
print() 
cursq.execute('SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type="table" AND name LIKE "%table%";')
tabgrab = cursq.fetchall()
for item in tabgrab:
    tabnames.append(item[0])
print(tabgrab)
for table in tabnames:
    print(table)
    cursq.execute("SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name = ?;", (table,))
    create = cursq.fetchone()[0]
    cursq.execute("SELECT * FROM %s;" %table)
    rows=cursq.fetchall()
    colcount=len(rows[0])
    pholder='%s,'*colcount
    newholder=pholder[:-1]

    try:
        conpg = psycopg2.connect(database=pgdb, user=pguser, password=pgpswd,
                               host=pghost, port=pgport)
        curpg = conpg.cursor()
        curpg.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s;" %table)
        create = create.replace("AUTOINCREMENT", "")
        curpg.execute(create)
        curpg.executemany("INSERT INTO %s VALUES (%s);" % (table, newholder),rows)
        conpg.commit()

        if conpg:
            conpg.close()

    except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
        print ('Error %s' % e) 
        sys.exit(1)

    finally:
        print("Complete")


consq.close()

duration = time.time() - start_time
print(f"Duration {duration} seconds")
```

My code with Asyncio module :

```
import psycopg2, sqlite3, sys
import time
import asyncio


sqdb="D://Python//SqliteToPostgreFull//testmydb6.db"
sqlike="table"
pgdb="testmydb9"
pguser="postgres"
pgpswd="1234"
pghost="127.0.0.1"
pgport="5432"


consq=sqlite3.connect(sqdb)
cursq=consq.cursor()

tabnames=[]
print() 
cursq.execute('''SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type="table" AND name LIKE "'''+sqlike+'''%";''')
tabgrab = cursq.fetchall()
for item in tabgrab:
    tabnames.append(item[0])
print(tabgrab)

async def copyTable(table):
    cursq.execute("SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name = ?;", (table,))
    create = cursq.fetchone()[0]
    cursq.execute("SELECT * FROM %s;" %table)
    rows=cursq.fetchall()
    colcount=len(rows[0])
    pholder='%s,'*colcount
    newholder=pholder[:-1]

    try:

        conpg = psycopg2.connect(database=pgdb, user=pguser, password=pgpswd,
                               host=pghost, port=pgport)
        curpg = conpg.cursor()
        curpg.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s;" %table)
        create = create.replace("AUTOINCREMENT", "")
        curpg.execute(create)
        curpg.executemany("INSERT INTO %s VALUES (%s);" % (table, newholder),rows)
        conpg.commit()

        if conpg:
            conpg.close()

    except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
        print ('Error %s' % e) 
        sys.exit(1)

    finally:
        print("Complete")

async def main():
    for table in tabnames:
        a = loop.create_task(copyTable(table,))
    await asyncio.wait([a])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.time()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()      
    duration = time.time() - start_time
    print(f"Duration {duration} seconds")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both databases located on a same computer, `asyncio` won't speedup a process: there's no network overhead to parallelize. Quite opposite: overhead for using coroutines will make program a bit slower.

Please, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51180506/1113207) for detailed explanation.